# Inject Html into column of Helper WebGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I use the helper WebGrid in my project. Data to display comes from database.

Now I want to Format a column with some HTML:

```
:
mGrid.Column(header: "Total<br>Current", format: @<text>@(Convert.ToString(item.images_total) + "<br>" + Convert.ToString(item.images_current))</text>),
:
```

But in the table I get the `<br>` written as text, not as HTML markup.
Same when using `Html.Raw`:

```
:
mGrid.Column(header: "Images Total<br>Current", format: @<text>@(Convert.ToString(item.images_total) + Html.Raw("<br>") + Convert.ToString(item.images_current))</text>),
:
```

The fields are `decimal` that´s why I convert them...

How can I inject HTML into my column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it on my own:

```
format: @<span>@Convert.ToString(item.images_total)<br>@Convert.ToString(item.images_current)</span>
```

But how to handle the 
 in my Header?

Comment: Same question. Did you find the answer?